# Why am I getting IOexception after creating a file and trying to write in it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, serialization, file-io, ioexception

I am just beginner so don't be harsh.
I am getting IOexception after trying to write to newly created file.

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Ivan\Desktop\Compilerv4liteXP\fcc\bin\Debug.default' because it is being used by another process.

So at the start of the method file is created (checked, it was there), but program ends (it returns false to be precise) in catch phase with given exception.

Method:

```
private static bool setDefaultValues()
    {
        if(!createFile(defaultValuesPath))
            return false;
        File.Exists(defaultValuesPath);
        DefaultValues dv = new DefaultValues(cygwinPath, userPath,bashPath,outputPath,outputGlobalPath,cygwinDownloadSite);
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(DefaultValues));
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(defaultValuesPath))
            {
                writer.Serialize(file, dv);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

createFile:

```
    private static bool createFile(string s)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(s))
        {
            try
            {
                File.Create(s);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Why is it happening and how can it be fixed (and by fixed I am thinking about trying to create a new file and if it succeeded (or file already exists) then write to it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode

Comment: The FileStream object created by this method has a default FileShare value of None; no other process or code can access the created file until the original file handle is closed.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File.Create()` returns a `FileStream` that locks the file.
You need to `Close()` it.

Better yet, get rid of that function entirely and `File.Open(path, FileMode.Create)`.